# ZF create a new controller

Tags: php, zend-framework, controller

I made my first project with ZF, used the Zend_Tool component.
For the index controller a created some actions, and they work well.
But my question is, when do you create a new controller?
thanks!

Answer (score 1):

As the Controller is a crucial part of the [MVC pattern, I suggest reading up a bit on 
this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller).

In a nutshell:

> The controller receives input and initiates a response by making calls on model objects.

So when to create a new controller totally depends on your application. Often, there is one controller per database table in your model. The controller usually would allow for handling [CRUD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Create,_read,_update_and_delete) requests and delegating them to your model to process them.

Check out

- http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/learning.quickstart.intro.html
- http://akrabat.com/zend-framework-tutorial/
- http://www.survivethedeepend.com/zendframeworkbook/en/1.0

Answer (score 0):

When you want to have a different page. Are you using different logic or trying to fulfil a completely different task?

It should be quite clear to you when you want to create a new Controller, it is because you are doing something completely different.